# Call constructor from other method in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I am not sure is that legal or not in C++:

```
class Image
{
     Image(int w, int h) // constructor
     {
            ...
     }

     Image GetSpecialImage()
     {
          Image rVal(10,10);
          return rVal;
     }
}
```

Do I need to use another middle level `init()` method to do this in C++? If yes, can you please show me how?

---

`EDIT:` Eventhough you say it's fine, it does not really do what I want to do... Let me give you some more code:

```
class Image
{
     float* data;
     int w;
     int h;

     Image(int w, int h) // constructor
     {
            this->w = w;
            this->h = h;
            data = (float*) malloc ( w * h * sizeof(float) );
     }

     Image GetSpecialImage()
     {
          Image rVal(this->w,this->h);

          for(i=0;i<this->w * this->h;i++)
          {
                rVal.data[i] = this->data[i] + 1;
          }

          return rVal;
     }
}

int main()
{
      Image temp(100, 100);
      Image result = temp.GetSpecialImage();
      cout<<result.data[0];

      return 0;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this part?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly legal.

Comment: See `Factory Method Pattern` here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Reading your edit, what is going wrong? Is it the bout that gives the wrong value?

Comment: @J_D: I get the same value. (temp.data[0] and result.data[0])

Comment: After fixing the various compilation errors (are you sure this is exactly the code you are debugging?), I get exactly what you would expect. 
(gdb) p temp.data[0]
$1 = 0
(gdb) p result.data[0]
$2 = 1
Are you testing with optimizations On or Off? I recommend initializing your float array with a memset and stepping with a debugger.

Comment: @J_D: It's not the same code, only a part of it. I removed the unneccessary parts to keep it simple to understand. I don't know how to on/off optimizataions. (I use visual studio.) I, already, initialize the array and print the output... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In C++ we also use the `new` operator over `malloc` but you can fix that memory leak by using a `std::vector<float>` member.

Comment: @J_D memset did the trick! I just don't understand ... Without memset it prints temp.data[0] = -431602080.000000 and result.data[0] = -431602080.000000. (same) After I seted 0 to all elements of the temp's data in Image(int w, int h) constructor; I get (0 and 3) as I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Seth said, that is legal.

Something you could change to make it work even better is to make `GetSpecialImage` a static function. A static function defined in a class is a class function instead of an object function. That means you don't need an object in order to call it.

It would then be called like this: `Image special = Image::GetSpecialImage();`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  I would just do this though

```
 Image GetSpecialImage()
 {            
     return Image(10,10);      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's nothing wrong with this code (well, except for returning a local, which is a no-no), I guess what you're looking for is a static constructor pattern. Like so:

```
class Image{
 public:
  static Image* GetSpecialImage(){
    return new Image(10,10);
  }
};

//and call it so
Image *i = Image::GetSpecialImage();
```

Comment: Returning a local variable by value is perfectly fine.

Comment: If it was returning a reference that *would* be bad.

Comment: While returning a variable by value is legal, care should be taken before doing it. It invokes the copy constructor, which in the case of an image could be lengthy and temporarily increase the needed memory. However, many compiler will optimize this by having the return made by a reference parameter such as void GetSpatialImate(Image& outImage).

Comment: But now you have a resource management issue. The client code needs to know how the library code allocated the `Image` resource and deallocate it appropriately. If you _have_ to allocate the `Image` dynamically it would be far better to encapsulate the resource in a smart pointer that encapsulates the required deallocation mechanis.

Comment: @J_D " returning a variable by value … invokes the copy constructor …". Except when it doesn't, like in the OP's case. See [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: @Rob, as I said, many compile will optimize this, but I was under the impression that this was compiler dependant. Like all optimizations, the compiler can optimize or not. It is all a matter of "do you rely on the compiler or do you make those obvious optimizations yourself"